# Reading string value from a text file to java arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to read string value by splitting `|` include white space from text file and store to Account class.This is my function for read text file.

```
public ArrayList<Account> loadAccount(String fn) throws IOException{     
    ArrayList<Account> account = new ArrayList<Account>();
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream(fn)));
    while(infile.hasNextLine()){
        String accountNo = infile.nextLine();
        String legencyNo = infile.nextLine();
        Account c = new Account(accountNo, legencyNo);
        account.add(c);
    }
    infile.close();
    return account;
}
```

This is Account class.

```
public class Account {
 private int id;
 private String accountNo;
 private String legencyNo;
}
```

This is AccountInformation.txt.

Account Number | Legacy Key | Description

80000001|7001111|

80000002| |

80000003|7001234|Testing

Update: This is my readFile class.Now, It's ok.I'm using StringUtils.

```
public static List<Account> readFile() {

    String file = "C:\\Dev\\JBoss\\UpdateAccountNumber\\source\\AccountInformation.txt";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String splitter = "\\|";
    List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<Account>();
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] accounts = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.split(line, splitter);
            String accountNo = "",legencyNo="";
            for(int i = 0;i<accounts.length;i++){
                if (i == 0){
                     accountNo = (accounts[0] == null) ? "" : accounts[0];
                }
                if (i==1){
                     legencyNo = (accounts[1] == null) ? "" : accounts[1];
                }
            }
            Account a = new Account(accountNo,legencyNo);
            accountList.add(a); 
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return accountList;
  }
```

Comment: So... you've stated what you want but what's your actual question? Why does your code not fulfil your requirements? Do you receive an error message? Incorrect behaviour? We'll need more information to provide an answer. Also please format code blocks by indenting four spaces rather than using backticks (`).

Comment: @Aiken, I want to read the above text file and convert to Account object.That's all i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed code:

Account class:

```
class Account
{
    private int id;
    private String accountNo;
    private String legencyNo;

    public Account(String accountNo, String legencyNo)
    {
        this.accountNo = accountNo;
        this.legencyNo = legencyNo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.accountNo + " " + this.legencyNo;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class Test
{
    public static List<Account> readFile()
    {
        String file = "C:\\workspace\\practise\\test.txt";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String splitter = "\\|";
        List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<Account>();
        try
        {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Account a = null;
                String[] accounts = line.split(splitter);
                if (accounts.length > 1)
                {
                    a = new Account(accounts[0], accounts[1]);
                } else
                {
                    a=new Account(accounts[0], "");
                }
                accountList.add(a);
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            if (br != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return accountList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Account> acct = readFile();
        for (Account account : acct)
        {
            System.out.println(account);
        }
    }
}
```

Test file:

```
Account Number|Legacy Key|Description
80000001|7001111|
80000002||
80000003|7001234|Testing
```

The problem in above code was that when you split in second record there is only one string present i.e 80000002, so you are trying to use accounts[1], but accounts length itself is 1 so you will have to handle with if clause on accounts.length. you can try above code its working. From next time i would suggest you to run your code in debug mode to check where you are getting exception.

Answer (score 2):

Just try as. Which mean `split string include space` .

```
String[] accounts = line.split(splitter, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your problem correctly, you need to change your loop

```
while(infile.hasNextLine()){
            String line= infile.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\|");
            Account c = new Account(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
            account.add(c);
        }
```

There are two reasons for that,

First, your all data required are in single line `80000001|7001111|`, so calling nextLine will bring you next row rather than data which you required

Second, it might cause you exception, as you are checking is next line exist, and ther you try to read two lines, which will obviousky fail if you have only one line

Comment: When i change loop, the result is like this.A
8
8
8

Comment: @KyawBo sorry my bad, fixed it, obviously you need to skip first line, as it contains header but this is different story